# How to get a name of member property from the parent object

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I want to implement *getMemberName* function via reflection

```
data class Inner(val prop: String)
data class Source(
    val member: String,
    val innerMember: Inner
)
fun getMemberName(source: Any, member: Any) : String {
    return "..."
}
fun main() {
  val demo = Source("asd", Inner("asd2"))
  val memberName = getMemberName(demo, demo.member)
  //result: 'member'

  val innerMemberName = getMemberName(demo, demo.innerMember.prop)
  //result: 'innerMember.prop'
}
```

Maybe somewere in reflection libs exist any common solution?

Comment: With the signature you've posted you can't do what you want. The moment you call `demo.member` you are retrieving the return value (a string in this case). There is nothing linking this return value to the function that returned it.

If you want to get the name of a function you can instead do `source::member.name`, but of course that doesn't fit that signature.

Comment: I believe it can be done via reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution

```
fun getMemberName(source: Any, member: Any, prefix: String = "") : String {
    val res = source::class.declaredMemberProperties.firstOrNull {
        it.getter.call(source) === member
    }?.name
    if(res != null) {
        return prefix + res
    }
    source::class.declaredMemberProperties.filter {
        !it.getter.call(source)!!.javaClass.kotlin.qualifiedName!!.startsWith("kotlin.")
    }.forEach {
        val res = getMemberName(it.getter.call(source)!!, member, prefix + it.name + ".")
        if(res.isNotEmpty()) {
            return prefix + res
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want, but I don't think you can find out the "path" from Source down to the second field in one go, because the field is dereferenced from where it is in the object hierarchy

```
class Inner {
    val prop = "x"
}
class Source {
    val member = "y"
    val innerMember = Inner()
}
fun getMemberName(source: Any, member: KProperty0<Any>) : String {
    return "${member.name} declared in ${member.javaField?.declaringClass?.name} has value ${member.get()}"
}

fun main() {
    val demo = Source()
    val memberName = getMemberName(demo, demo::member)
    println(memberName) // prints: member declared in Source has value y

    val innerMemberName = getMemberName(demo, demo.innerMember::prop)
    println(innerMemberName) // prints: prop declared in Inner has value x
}
```

if you want to build a the path from source down N levels deep to a field, that'll be harder as you have devise someway to pass down the property references.  A "Bean Accessor" approach might be more what you need, something like [Apache Commons PropertyUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.4/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html#standard.nested)

Comment: This is not what i am searching for. I want to use getMemberName function with assertion library to log the name of properties which a not equals.